# Python Tkinter Updating label text leaves old text there until the function exits

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am building a simple GUI using python and tkinter, its a Magic 8 Ball problem. My issue comes when I am trying to update the text that is being shown by the response label while inside the ASK function. I wanted to try update it a few times so that it would blink between --- and " [Blank] " for a few seconds before giving an answer. But it seems to just overlay the new text ontop of the old text until the ASK function is complete, when the last text to be put there is the only one that remains.

Is this simply because I can only update once inside a function? Or is there a simple way around this?

Code, cut out as much as I could to show the error:

```
import time
import random
from tkinter import *

responses=[]
responses.append("No")
responses.append("Yes")
responses.append("I don't think so")    

class TheGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Python Magic 8 Ball GUI")

        self.label = Label(self.master, text="Enter a Question you would like to ask (no to quit):")
        self.label.pack()

        self.enterplace = Entry(self.master)
        self.enterplace.pack()

        self.labeltext=StringVar()
        self.labeltext.set("--")
        self.response = Label(self.master, justify=CENTER, textvariable=self.labeltext)
        self.response.pack()

        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(self.frame, text="Ask", command=self.ask)
        self.greet_button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.close_button = Button(self.frame, text="Clear", command=self.clear)
        self.close_button.pack(side=LEFT)

    # This is the function in question
    def ask(self):
        the_q = self.enterplace.get()

        if the_q == "no":
            self.labeltext.set("Okay, Goodbye..")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.master.quit
        else:
            self.labeltext.set("Let me think for a moment")
            self.master.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(2)

            # Here, when I update the label to be ---, the previous text 
            # remains as a background, and only disappears once this 
            # function has exited. I was initially trying to make the --- 
            # blink once or twice, but ran into this error

            self.labeltext.set("---")
            self.master.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(2)

            self.labeltext.set(random.choice(responses))
            self.master.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(2)

    def clear(self):
        self.labeltext.set("")
        self.master.update_idletasks()


root = Tk()
my_gui = TheGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The following image shows the text overlay, "Let me think for a moment" and "I don't think so"

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem with the code you shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had almost everything right ! What worked for me was to replace `self.master.update_idletasks()` with `self.master.update()`

```
        self.labeltext.set("Let me think for a moment")
        self.master.update()
        # self.master.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(2)

        self.labeltext.set("---")
        self.master.update()
        # self.master.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.labeltext.set(random.choice(responses))
        self.master.update()
        # self.master.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(2)
```

However I don't understand why `update_idletasks()` does not work in this case...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the:

```
self.master.update()
```

instead of the:

```
self.master.update_idletasks()
```

and you are good to go. 
At least it works for me on Python 2.7